# SQL: clientside-to-serverside and back

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql

I have a javascript variable - type: var.

How do I pass this from the client side to the server side...and then use the value stored in the variable to do SQL queries in C# (asp.net)

(So far I have only done SQL queries with variables on the server side.)

and then after executing query, error checking; how do I return the result to the client side (javascript) and extract the useful information and apply it to my client side functionalities ?

Algorithm:- 
1) accept var in client side 2) send request to server 3) accept on server side 4) use the query values (say firstname) and execute SQL query 5) check for result 6) if error then post error message else return result 7) accept result on client side 8) parse result and extract useful informatiom 9) use this information for client side functionalities.

Any ideas? Links with sample code ? What is this process formally called ? (maybe something like REST Web Service or other formalized names? )

Please help.

Thanks.

```
Var mem_ID = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').value;
```

Now How do I pass this onto the server side??

Comment: This isn't a good question for SO, as you really need to read a book or do tutorials. There is too much to cover. Can start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4

Comment: Agreed! There's a lot more to this than just a simple question

Comment: Start by learning how to use plain HTML forms.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev nice tutorial! That's one I'll go through too especially since MVC is my next frontier. Thanks! I think it's the "Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4" tutuorial that will help this subject, specifically

Comment: @Jimmmy that tutorial is a good intro. Another decent walk-through (has similar content) - http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Wrox-Guides/dp/111834846X

Comment: In addition to the link @MikeSmithDev posted, download a full sample so you can see the whole process from end to end: http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would work is an AJAX call to a server side aspx.net file. Have it return the text value you like and then on the client side the JavaScript can recieve it and do with it what you like.

This can be a complicated process. But that would be where you would begin your research.

[Here's a link to get started](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP).

Comment: w3schools is not where you begin research.

Comment: I have been looking at Ajax, Jquery, and Json, also Rest WEb Services... however I need to look at something simple... also been reading the book Pro ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010. Whoever voted me down on this question for not doing research must be upset with his/her current day. :)

Comment: w3Schools is Not the best @MikeSmithDev is correct, but it's a great place to get your feet wet. I've been doing AJAX stuff for about 6 years now. And while my methods may be a bit different from what others are using, they are effective and I got my start at W3CSchools. The areas you're looking are all the right places, but think of this as a journey and not a destination

Comment: @Philosophia your question is getting voted down (no, I didn't vote you down) because its overly broad and didn't talk about any of your research or show any effort. If you go through the tutorial link I sent, you'll probably find what you are looking for. Or at least get started.

Comment: BTW... voting down has nothing to do with YOU personally, but rather with keeping the value of the site high. Questions that have high points get higher value on the search engines. While questions that have low points don't work well with the main goals of the site. The tempation is to take it personal, but I wouldn't do that. Just ask more focused questions... AFTER you've done your research already! (It wasn't me either ;)

Comment: Oh I didnt take it personally. However have you heard of something like: there is no bad question, everyone needs to start somewhere...just like you started on W3 with ajax. People learn at different paces and in different ways... to quantify the value of a question is emperically impossible... so is the value of this site. representative methods of quantifying always leaves some people behind. but thats another story. Thanks for all your suggestions. I m on my way.!!

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
 xmlhttp.send();

now as far as i understand, for the URL, in my case I think I will just be sending it to the page with my SQL query? but if that is correct then how does the server know the name of the variable i am sending and what value it contains?

Comment: @Philosophia This is why it's not an easy question. Doing this kind of work takes on many disciplines, JavaScript makes the call (perhaps to a asp.net page), using a query string the recieving page (perhaps asp.net) can read the query string value, act on it by performa a DB function (SQL query) then return the text value as a built asp.net page displaying the value. I hope this helps, but again, it's multi-faceted

Comment: thanks Jimmmy..this truely is multi faceted.

Comment: Hang in there. We all start somewhere and it's never too late. Let me tell you though, when that first async call works and you get that data from the DB... I remember I said out loud "Holy .... it actually worked!". It's a lot of fun IMO (I know, adds nothing to the site... but encouragement is important too :)